# How to add .lib files in C static linking? (undefined reference to error)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, undefined-reference, lib

I am trying a sample IXChariot API. These are the requirements before compiling and running the C file.

[IX Chariot C API requiements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIqQv.png). I have added both the include files and the lib files in the source directory I am working on, as said in the changes.

I have tried to add these path to environment variables as said in the API. But when during compilation of the main.c file, I am getting a undefined reference to error.

Error Received during compilation:- undefined reference to `CHR_api_initialize'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The CHR_api_initialize is already defined in the header file(chrapi.h), but I am getting an undefined reference error. I am not much familiar with C as I am with other languages.

The code and file structure is in this reddit link as Stackoverflow does not allow me to upload my code eventhough it is formatted.  [Link for file structure and code](https://www.reddit.com/user/Calm_Maize7538/comments/10nca8i/how_to_add_lib_files_in_c_static_linking/)

Can anyone help me on this and point out what needs to be corrected?

Comment: You want to tell us how you are linking your binary.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the issue, I am receiving this error. So if l know the linking procedure, I think it will help in solving the issue.

Comment: I tried using this command :- >gcc -I ./lib -c ChrApi.lib main.c to check if I was able to link the lib files but still it is not working.

Comment: You want to edit your question with that information along with the exact error message you get.  -I is to find the header, but you want to use -L to find the library.  Is your library really called ChrApi.lib?  That's an unusual name.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason for this error, that's why I named the question name like this. And yes ChrApi.lib is the library file mentioned in the docs. You can refer the same through the image link I attached.

Comment: I rarely follow external links or read through all comments which is why you want to update the question with new information.  If you cannot follow through on the suggestions given then it's too much work to help you.  Order of files matters which is why I need to see the exact command you used.  The next thing is you want to check what type of file ChrApi.lib is (c or an archive).  On Linux you would use `file ChrApi.lib`.  You seem to be using Windows, and from what I read you cannot link object files build with different compilers.